# How do I sort a list of IP addresses and compute a class and netmask for each?

Tags: perl, ip, perl-module

I have 2 options. One is that I have a array that has a list of IPs. For example

```
 my @Ip=();  # array that has the IPs below in it
```

Sample input:

```
108.0.0.30
108.0.0.30
108.0.0.30
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
10.0.0.1
```

I need a program that can sort such an array and tell which network class and subnet mask it is. For example, the output should be like

```
10.1.1.1/25                          10.1.1.1 is ip and 25 is submask
```

Comment: You can't tell which subnet an IP addres belongs to without additional information

Comment: how should i add more information ?

Answer (score 3):

[`Net::IP`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-IP/IP.pm), [`Net::IP::Resolver`](http://search.cpan.org/~adamk/Net-IP-Resolver-0.02/lib/Net/IP/Resolver.pm), [`Net::IP::Match::Regexp`](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/Net-IP-Match-Regexp-1.01/lib/Net/IP/Match/Regexp.pm) and other Submodules from `Net::IP` are doing that fine for you. Just the part with sorting is difficult. But if you google it, you find some nice Methods. For example:

```
my @ips = qw(
    172.27.32.200
    172.19.32.100
    10.1.1.60
    192.20.30.133
);

@ips = map {s/\s+//g; $_} sort map {s/(\d+)/sprintf "%3s", $1/eg; $_} @ips;

print join "\n", @ips;
```

[Found here](http://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/655019-how-sort-ip-address-using-perl-script#post2598599)